# Javascript - Get div height, then apply css to another div '100vh minus div height'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do next in Javascript:

1. Get dynamic height of header
2. Apply CSS to another div: calc(100vh - height of header)

My current code is: (it's not working)

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
var bannerHeight = document.getElementById('banner');
bannerHeight.style.height = '100vh' - offsetHeight;
```

Comment: This sounds a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). While you *can* do this (see my answer below), ideally you wouldn't have to. Modern CSS has features for making it possible to have an element fill the remaining space of a container. With more information about the problem, it might be possible to solve this with CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [CSS `calc` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
bannerHeight.style.height = `calc(100vh - ${offsetHeight}px)`;
```